# Reversing order of Mongo $sort fails to reverse the order

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a pipeline, something like this:

```js
db.entrycodes.aggregate(
  {
    '$match' : {
      usedAt:{
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      usedAt: true,
      dayOfMonth: {
        '$dayOfMonth': '$usedAt'
      },
      month: {
        '$month': '$usedAt'
      },
      year: {
        '$year': '$usedAt'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        dayOfMonth: '$dayOfMonth',
        month: '$month',
        year: '$year'
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      year:1,
      month:1,
      dayOfMonth: 1
    }
  }
)
```

The last operator $sorts on the year month and dayOnMonth fields. The issue is that the data comes out reverse sorted every time. If I rewrite the last part of the query like this:

```js
  {
    $sort: {
      year: -1,
      month: -1,
      dayOfMonth: -1
    }
  }
```

the data remains reverse sorted, which appears to be contrary to the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/).

Is this a bug in Mongo, or am I missing something obvious?

*mongod version: 2.6.9*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$sort` stage is wrong you need to use the so called [*dot notation*](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation)

```js
{
    $sort: {
        "_id.year" : -1,
        "_id.month" : -1,
        "_id.dayOfMonth": -1
    }
}
```

Comment: Bah, the apparent sort was an artifact of order of insertion. Thanks for looking at it.